# How do I view all desktop panels in Budgie?

Tags: budgie

I am used to Ubuntu Mate where you are able to view all desktop panels at the bottom right-hand side of the screen.

Is there an option to have an icon or shortcut keys to display all desktop panels?

Comment: re "desktop panels" - are you referring to all your workspaces?

Answer (score 6):

To get the virtual desktop indicator, do the following:

- Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Press the gear icon in the upper right corner
- Click **Panel**
- Next to **Applets** press the <kbd>+</kbd> button
- Double click <kbd>workspace switcher</kbd>

It will then be added in the center next to the clock.

To move the applet:

- Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Press the gear icon in the upper right corner
- Click **Panel**
- Select the applet and use the up/down arrows to move it to your desired position.